# AWS WAF not blocking requests using aws_wafregional_regex_pattern_set

Tags: terraform

I'm kind of surprised that I'm running into this problem. I created an `aws_wafregional_regex_pattern_set` to block incoming requests that contain php in their URI. I expected all requests with php in them to be blocked. However the requests are still making it through. Perhaps, I'm misunderstanding what this resource actually does? I have attached some sample code below.

```
resource "aws_wafregional_rule" "block_uris_containining_php" {
  name = "BlockUrisContainingPhp"
  metric_name = "BlockUrisContainingPhp"

  predicate {
    data_id = "${aws_wafregional_regex_match_set.block_uris_containing_php.id}"
    negated = false
    type = "RegexMatch"
  }

}

resource "aws_wafregional_regex_match_set" "block_uris_containing_php" {
  name = "BlockUrisContainingPhp"

  regex_match_tuple {
    field_to_match {
      type = "URI"
    }

    regex_pattern_set_id = "${aws_wafregional_regex_pattern_set.block_uris_containing_php.id}"
    text_transformation = "NONE"
  }
}

resource "aws_wafregional_regex_pattern_set" "block_uris_containing_php" {
  name = "BlockUrisContainingPhp"
  regex_pattern_strings = [ "php$" ]
}
```

This code creates a `String and regex matching condition` in AWS WAF. So, I know it's at least getting created. I used cloudwatch to check for blocked requests as I sent requests containing php to the load balancer, but each request went through successfully. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell from snippet but did you add the rule to web ACL and set the rule action to block?

Also you should try using `wafv2` instead of `wafregional` as `wafv2` comes with new features and easier to express rules.

Comment: I'm using `aws_wafregional_web_acl_association` to associate the `aws_alb` to the web acl.

Comment: I assume you did but you will have to add the rule to the web ACL as well.